# Alt H Brings Object Into View - Weight Paint Makes It Disappear

Tags: objects, weight-painting, sculpt, sculpt-mode, weight-paint-mode

I've Made A Thread On Reddit Too....

Video In Thread....

It Seems Like I Used To Need A Script To Fix This Issue....

Link To File:

[image]

Is My Object Merely Off Screen....??

Alt H Bringing It Into View....

Weight Paint Returning It To Off Screen Position....???

I've Applied Location Rotation And Scale To Deltas, Visual, Normal Ect....

No Luck....

https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/ywk0g5/encountered_massive_weight_paint_issue_in_blender/

Nothing Seems To Work....

Same Thing Occurs In Sculpt Mode....

/ To Local View....

Is Not A Fix Here....

Any Help Would Be Appreciated

Thank You....!!

Comment: Can you upload the file so we can taka a look? Use https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with facesets. I've had a problem with it a few times ago where the faces where hidden in Sculpt Mode and I didn't know how to bring them back. Not sure if it's a bug or the facesets work in a way that are really not intuitive.

Anyway, **reinitializing the face sets** should solve your problem :

Switch to Sculpt mode and go to `Face Sets` > `Initialize Face Sets` > `By Loose Parts` :

[image: Initialize Face Sets]

After that you should have your geometry back :

[image: Geometry visible in Sculpt Mode]

Now your mesh should be visible in all Modes :

[image: Weight Paint Mode]
[image: Edit Mode]

For some reason, with this file you uploaded, the mesh didn't dissapear in Weight Paint Mode so I can't know for sure what the cause of that problem would be. My guess is that the vertices may just have been hidden and pressing <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> should unhide them if you have `Paint Mask` or `Vertex Selection` activated.

Comment: So In Your Instance.... Weight Painting On The Mesh Did Not Cause The Mesh To Disappear....??

I Will Attempt The Above Solution.... Thank You....!!

Comment: This Solution Seemed To Have Worked....!! Thank You....!!

Comment: Glad, I helped.

Comment: @GarrettSmith Just one thing which I guess is not intended - and it's unrelated from the disappearing faces - but might cause problems in the future is that on one half of the object the faces are flipped. So one side faces upwards, the other downwards.